# mean of 3d points as minimization task

Tags: python, gradient, points, mean

I have a set of `n`  3D points `(x,y,z)` and I would like to compute its mean.

In particular my purpose is to compare the differences between several metric.

Euclidean distance: `D_E(D_1,D_2) = ||D_1 - D_2||`

Riemannian distance: `D_R(D_1,D_2) = ||log(D_1^(-1/2) * D_2 * D_1^(-1/2))||`

Once I fix a metric, I should compute a minimization problem.

I founded in Python Scipy.optimize for this kind of task, but I do not know how formulate the problem. Should I use a for loop?

Edit:

I found *scipy.optimize.leastsq* . It seems to be useful, for my goal. How could I use it in a gradient descent framework?

Comment: Why do you need a minimization routine to calculate the mean?  You can calculate it directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[7,-100,8]])
>>> a.mean(axis=0)
array([  3.        , -32.        ,   4.66666667])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without extra libraries:

```
>>> make_operation = lambda op: lambda *points: tuple(map(op, *points))

>>> add = make_operation(lambda x1, x2: x1 + x2)
>>> sub = make_operation(lambda x1, x2: x1 - x2)

>>> print add((1,2,3), (4,5,6))
(3,5,7)

>>> div = lambda point, num: tuple(map(lambda x: float(x) / num, point))
>>> print div((4,6,8), 2)
(1,2,3)

>>> mean = lambda *points: div(reduce(add, points), len(points))
>>> print mean((1,2,3), (1,2,3), (7,-100,8))
(3.0, -32.0, 4.666666666666667)
```

Comment: This is a way for computing the centroid. Not really what I ask. I need a more general procedure for computing a mean point given a chosen metric (like Euclidean, Riemannian, log, ...)

Comment: @no_name: It's possible you're not looking for the mean.  I can't think of an example of a mean that can't be computed directly,

Comment: It depends on the metric you choose. A "mean" point of a set is a kind of representative of the set of points that minimizes the distance between it and any other point. I am pretty confident it is a minimization problem that can be solved by gradient descent. Now my problem is finding a light implementation in python.